# Thread and progressDialog android

Tags: java, android

I have a function that requires a lot of calculation, so I try to call that function inside a thread. This is how I do it:

```
  submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!(fromAdress.getText().toString().length() > 0) || !(toAdress.getText().toString().length() > 0)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR IN INPUT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
            }
            else {
                if(connected) {

                    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Calculating", 
                            "Please wait...", true);
                            final Handler handler = new Handler() {
                               public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                                  dialog.dismiss();
                                  }
                               };
                            Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {  
                               public void run() {

                                  measureDistanceAndTime(fromAdress.getText().toString(), toAdress.getText().toString());

                                  handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                                  }
                               };
                            checkUpdate.start();
                }

                else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No network!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
```

When I open the application, it shows the progressdialog, but after like 4 seconds, it stops responding. I cant figure out this problem, cuz when I remove the code for the thread and progressdialog, it works fine!

Isn't this the way to do it?

Comment: Any errors? Do you get an "application not responding message"? If you let it run does it come back or does it hang indefinitely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with an `AsyncTask`. Read this article entitled [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure why your particular situation isn't working, but you'll probably have better luck using an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of trying to do raw threads.  It handles most of the UI vs. other thread strangeness that can lead to problems.  The conceptual model isn't much different than what you've got there, so it should be an easy change.

Answer (score 2):

You need an [AsynTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing in UI Thread. So when some message action hold over 5 seconds, they will notice infamous message: not responsing.

You should put long-work in other thread. In your case, because you are interacting with UI THread, the most benefit way is use Asyntask